# Two Problems with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have two problems with fullcalendar that I can't solve.

The first is that when I add or update an event, I call the `refetchEvents()` function but it gives me the following error on the console and doesn't update the events:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refetchEvents')
```

The code where I call `refetchEvents()`:

```
function agregarRegistro(registro) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'datoseventos.php?accion=agregar',
                data: registro,
                success: function(msg) {
                    calendario1.refetchEvents();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    //alert("Hay un problema:" + error);
                    calendario1.refetchEvents();
                }
            });
        }
```

Where `calendario1` is called:

```
    var calendario1;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario1');
            var taller = '<?php echo $tare;?>'
            var user = '<?php echo $ctrl_user;?>'
            var userfiltro = '0'
  var calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    locale: 'es',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'datoseventos.php?accion=listarempleados&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
    //resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
   events: 'datoseventos.php?accion=listar&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
```

The second error is when I load the appointments (From a database). The problem is that the appointment loads fine, but the time is not displayed correctly. For example, if the appointment starts on June 16 at 07:00 I correctly receive this from the database:

```
 {"allDay":false,"title":"yyyyyyyy","start":"2023-06-16T07:00:00Z","end":"2023-06-16T10:00:00Z","id":"8281","backgroundColor":"#FFFF00","textColor":"#ffffff","extendedProps":{"descripcion":"","idtra":"0","iduser":"88","tipo_parte":"0"}}
```

However, in the time selector of the modal, I get 09:00. If I print it through the console, it also gives me 9.

```
LA HORA ES 09:00
```

My Modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="FormularioEventos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="Codigo">
                <input type="hidden" id="idveh">
                <input type="hidden" id="tiempocita" value="60">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label>Titulo de la Cita:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                        <input type="hidden" id="idtall" name="idtall" value="<?php echo $tare ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label>Empleado que ejecuta el trabajo:</label>
                         <?php
                            $comprobar_user = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_empresa = '$id_empresa' AND idtaller = '$tare'");
                              echo "<select class='custom-select' name='iduser' id='iduser'>";
                            ?>
                             <option value='0' <?php if($ctrl_user == 0){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Todos</option>
                        <?php
                              while ($fila1=mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_user)) {
                                  echo "<option  value='".$fila1["id"]."' ".$marcaidtaller.">".$fila1["nombre"]." </option>";
                              }
                                echo "</select>";

                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Fecha de Inicio:</label>

                        <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                            <input type="date" id="FechaInicio" value="" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="TituloHoraInicio">
                        <label>Hora de inicio:</label>

                        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                            <input type="text" id="HoraInicio" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Fecha de Fin:</label>

                        <div class="input-group" data-autoclose="true">
                            <input type="date" id="FechaFin" value="" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="TituloHoraFin">
                        <label>Hora de fin:</label>

                        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                            <input type="text" id="HoraFin" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Descripcion :</label>
                    <textarea id="Descripcion" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Color de Fondo:</label>
                    <select id="ColorFondo" class="form-control" style="height:36px;">
                      <option value="#0000FF" id="option-1" selected>Azul</option>
                      <option value="#00008B" id="option-6">Azul Oscuro</option>
                      <option value="#FFFF00" id="option-5">Amarillo</option>
                      <option value="#808080" id="option-4">Gris</option>
                      <option value="#00FF00" id="option-10">Lima</option>
                      <option value="#FFA500" id="option-8">Naranja</option>
                      <option value="#000000" id="option-9">Negro</option>
                      <option value="#808000" id="option-7">Oliva</option>
                      <option value="#F8B88B" id="option-12">Pastel</option>
                      <option value="#FF0000" id="option-3">Rojo</option>
                      <option value="#FF00FF" id="option-11">Rosa</option>
                      <option value="#008000" id="option-2">Verde</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Color de Texto:</label>
                    <input type="color" value="#ffffff" id="ColorTexto" class="form-control" style="height:36px;">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" id="BotonAgregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
                <button type="button" id="BotonModificar" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" id="BotonOt" class="btn btn-success">Abrir Parte</a>
                <button type="button" id="BotonBorrar" class="btn btn-success">Borrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
                console.log("EL RES ES "+JSON.stringify(info.event));
                console.log("LA HORA ES "+moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                $('#BotonModificar').show();
                if (info.event.extendedProps.idtra != 0) {
                    if (info.event.extendedProps.tipo_parte != 0) {
                        $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_contado.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                    } else {
                        $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_cia.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#BotonOt').hide();
                }
                $('#BotonBorrar').show();
                $('#BotonAgregar').hide();
                $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);
                $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                $('#idtra').val(info.event.idtra);
                $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                $("#FormularioEventos").modal();
            },
```

Comment: You are calling `refetchEvents` on `calendario1`, but what you have shown us so far gives us no indication, where that variable is supposed to come from.

Comment: `"start":"2023-06-16T07:00:00Z"` - the `Z` at the end means Zulu timezone, basically UTC. If you are working in a different time zone, you might need to modify that.

Comment: The second issue is timezone mismatch, check the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone) on how to handle that.

Comment: `var calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(...)` - by using the `var` keyword there, you made this one a _local_ variable in the scope of the DOMContentLoaded callback function. Remove the keyword, so that `calendario1` at this point refers to the _global_ variable you created.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses! I solved the time problem simply by changing timeZone: 'UTC', for timeZone: 'local', I just need to know if you can help me with the other problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry CBroe, but I've been programming for a while and I don't understand your answer, do you mind explaining it to me? Thank you.

Comment: @FranciscoS `var calendario1 = new FullCalendar....` remove `var` you want it to be `calendario1 = new FullCalendar`. The problem CBroe is referring to, is that when you re-declare `var calendario = ` inside of your `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...` you made the variable *local to the scope* of the DOMContentLoaded event listener/callback. Nothing outside of that Event Listener is in scope for that variable. If you simply update the *global* variable you set **outside** your Event Listener, it will be available to your AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for your help. For who may need it:

1)-The problem that the wrong time was displayed:

I just changed this:

```
timeZone: 'UTC',
```

For this:

```
timeZone: 'local',
```

2)-The problem that refetchEvents() did not serve:

I implemented I removed the VAR in the call, which was like this:

```
var calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
```

and it was like this:

```
calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
```